# Split list into different variables

Tags: python, list, iterable-unpacking

I have a list like this:

```py
[('love', 'yes', 'no'), ('valentine', 'no', 'yes'), ('day', 'yes','yes')]
```

How do I split this list into three variables where each variable holds one tuple, i.e.

```
var1 = ('love', 'yes', 'no')
var2 = ('valentine', 'no', 'yes')
var3 = ('day', 'yes','yes')
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Assign to three names:

```
var1, var2, var3 = listobj
```

Demo:

```
>>> listobj = [('love', 'yes', 'no'), ('valentine', 'no', 'yes'), ('day', 'yes','yes')]
>>> var1, var2, var3 = listobj
>>> var1
('love', 'yes', 'no')
>>> var2
('valentine', 'no', 'yes')
>>> var3
('day', 'yes', 'yes')
```

Comment: How would split each list, var1/var2/var3, into a separate words? The `split()` method does not seem to work on list objects.

Comment: Got it! `[i.split()[0] for i in var1]`

Comment: How to do this for an argument list?  E.g. `def myfunc(a,b,c,d):`

Comment: @javadba: what do you mean? You want to pass in a list as 4 separate arguments? Then use the `*` call syntax: `myfunc(*listobj_with_4_values)`.

Comment: Yes that is what I were looking for (the equivalent of scala's `:_*` . thx!

Comment: How do I split it if I don't know how many variables there are?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `*` to unpack into different variables. It's useful if you don't know how many variables to list split into or if only a few variables are needed out of a list.

```py
lst = [('love', 'yes', 'no'), ('valentine', 'no', 'yes'), ('day', 'yes','yes')]

first, *rest = lst
first  # ('love', 'yes', 'no')
rest   # [('valentine', 'no', 'yes'), ('day', 'yes', 'yes')]

# unpack the last variable
*rest, last = lst

# unpack the first two
first, second, *rest = lst

# unpack the first three
first, second, third, *rest = lst
```